# How to recalculate all formulas before first sheet is displayed?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, xml

I have developped `VB.Net` program that create an `Excel` file and fill a sheet using RecordSet obtained from an Postgres SQL SELECT.

My program works without using any Microsoft Excel Assembly, but only in writing XML file in .XLSX file.

My program works well but I have some issues with formulas applicated on rows as SUM or SUMIF or COUNT or MAX or MIN.

In XML file named `Sheet1.xml`, I have generated followed XML part

```
<row r="91" x14ac:dyDescent="0.25" spans="1:7">
    <c r="E91" s="14" t="n">
        <f>SUM(E4:E89)</f>
        <v>0</v>
    </c>
</row>
```

Normally, this cell must display '5012' as number (that is sum of cells E4 to E89), but my program has not done the computation and cell's value is set to 0.

When I load my generated Excel file, `Excel` display 0 in this cell.

To refresh this cell to display correct value, I must press on Ctrl+Alt+Shift+F9.

Question:

Does exist a **XML element or attribute** that forces Excel to recalculate all formulas after a sheet has been loaded and before first sheet is displayed so that correct computed formula value is displayed ?

I search a solution at XML level that avoid pressing Ctrl+Alt+Shift+F9 keys.

Comment: In Excel, is *File > Options > Formulas > Calculation options section > Workbook Calculation* set to Automatic?

Comment: Yes it is set to automatic

Comment: Is the cell with the formula in question formatted as Text or Number?

Comment: as Number. It is visible in question. See t="n" !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve your issue, you must simply remove `<v>` element !

I have tried with Excel and LibreOffice and this work with both applications.

New XML code for your cell must be

```
<row r="91" x14ac:dyDescent="0.25" spans="1:7">
    <c r="E91" s="14" t="n">
        <f>SUM(E4:E89)</f>
    </c>
</row>
```

If you save displayed Excel sheet, Excel with then add a `<v>` element.

After saving displayed Excel file, you can now see following lines.

```
<row r="91" x14ac:dyDescent="0.25" spans="1:7">
    <c r="E91" s="14" t="n">
        <f>SUM(E4:E89)</f>
        <v>5553.0000000000018</v
    </c>
</row>
```

Comment: I have removed <v> element directly in sheet1.xml files contained in my compressed XLSX file and I have reloaded in Excel saved file and your proposal is working fine. Thanks